# Cannot Connect to the App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

I have an App Store update indicated on my App store icon, but when I click on it to go to the App store I get the message >Cannot Connect to App Store

Comment: Check your internet connection, that the problem.

Comment: Did you type your question whilst on the same machine that cannot connect to the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

There are two places you need to check, both under "Settings": "Mobile" and "App Store." Under "Mobile", find Use mobile data for: and scroll down until you find App Store. Make sure the switch is toggled to green. Next, go back to Settings and scroll down until you see "iTunes & App Store." Click on that and make sure "Use mobile data" is toggled to green.

If you are in the US or another region, "Mobile" may be labelled "Cellular" and "Use mobile data" may be "Use cellular data"

Here are two screen shots to help direct you:

[image: Screenshot of iOS Settings menu with red arrow pointing to fourth item down]

And this:

[image: Screenshot of iOS Settings menu with red arrow pointing to iTunes & App Store just below iCloud]

Comment: I cannot find "mobile" under settings.

Comment: This may vary depending on regional settings. If you are in the US, I believe you need to substitute "Cellular" for "Mobile" in most of the above. I will post screen shots in an additional answer.